# How to predefine the cursor position in command?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line

I'm trying to create a custom key mapping which start bring up commandline mode with some text inserted. I would like to have the cursor position not at the end but in a specific position, like this:

```
:%s/|/nextposition/g
```

Where `|` represents the cursor.

It would be perfect if the cursor could be positioned to the `nextposition` place if user types `<Tab>` or some other key stroke.

How to achieve this?

Comment: With `<Left><left><Left>`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use that:

```
nnoremap <key> :s//nextposition/g<c-b><right><right>
```

The mapping will first go into command mode: `:`

Then write `s//nextposition/g` in the command lines

Go to the beginning of the command `<c-b>`

And move to the desired position: `<right>`

Some interesting command line mappings can be found here: [`:h cmdline-editing`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-editing)

---

Now about the part where you want to move the cursor to another place with `<tab>` it is something that you can do in insert mode with a snippet engine like UltiSnips but I'm not sure you can make it work in command line.

---

Also not exactly related but Damian Conway has two pretty interesting mappings described in his [how I vim](http://howivim.com/2016/damian-conway/):

First he says that to simplify his substitutions he created the following mapping:

```
nmap  S  :%s//g<LEFT><LEFT>
```

So he can press `S` and then just `pattern/replacement` to do the substitution.

Then to improve it he created the following:

```
nmap <expr>  M  ':%s/' . @/ . '//g<LEFT><LEFT>'
```

This way he can make a search `/pattern`, see the results and simply type `M` followed by the replacement string and the pattern is automatically added to the substitution command. *(Note that it is convenient to see the pattern in the command but doing `:%s//replacement/g` will also use the last search pattern)*

I know that it is not what OP is asking for but I thought it could be an inspiration source.

Comment: +1000 Wow, thank you, I'm using this for vifm